# how to disable input when the value is empty laravel livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

i am using livewire , laravel 7. Below is the code. How to make sure the input is readonly when the value is empty?

```html
 <div class="form-row">
                    @foreach($serviceOrder as $o)
                        <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
                            <label class="form-control-label" >Service {{ $loop->iteration }} </label>
                            <input type="text"  wire:model="serviceOrder.{{ $loop->index }}.serv.serviceName" class="form-control " readonly>
                           
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden"  wire:model="serviceOrder.{{ $loop->index }}.serv.servicePrice" class="form-control col-sm-1 mb-3" readonly>
                       
                        <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                            <label class="form-control-label" >Weight/Size</label>
                            <input type="text" name="" value=""  wire:model="serviceOrder.{{ $loop->index }}.weightsize"  class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                            
                            <label class="form-control-label" >Quantity*opt</label>
                                <input type="text" name="" value="" wire:model="serviceOrder.{{ $loop->index }}.quantity"  class="form-control" @if(!$quantity)  readonly @endif >
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                    </div>
```

the one i am focusing is this part

```
 <div class="col-md-3 mb-3"> 
                        <label class="form-control-label" >Quantity*opt</label>
                            <input type="text" name="" value="" wire:model="serviceOrder.{{ $loop->index }}.quantity"  class="form-control" @if(!$quantity)  readonly @endif >
                    </div>
```

for the input that has no value, should be " ", it is a nullable variable for quantity
[image: picture example]

Comment: You're using strict equality checking so what does an `empty` `quantity` value look like? Is it actually `null`, or is it `""` or `0`?

Comment: @Peppermintology it suppose to be 0,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding this check in the element:

```
<input type="text" wire:model="serviceOrder.{{ $loop->index }}.quantity"  class="form-control" @if(!$serviceOrder[$loop->index]['quantity']) readonly @endif>
```

Comment: do i have to remove the one i did and just paste that?? :)

Comment: @leabelle You can replace what you have with this example, however, you'll need to change it slightly to `@if (!$quantity) readonly @endif` as otherwise using the above will apply `readonly` when `$quantity` has a non empty value.

Comment: @Peppermintology it still readonly on the input that has value... do we need to add something in if condition?

Comment: @leabelle Can you update your question with your current code?

Comment: @leabelle I edited my answer as Peppermintology suggests. My bad

Comment: @Prospero still not working tho, the input that has value still set as readonly

Comment: ahh, but $quantity don't exist as property, it's a model property or array index...UPDATED